# How to use variables in calculations when defining a new TikZ command

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I'm trying to define a new command to use in a TikZ picture. but it seems I can't work with variables (in this case the `\def`s) inside the newcommand definition. At least not the way I am doing it right now:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\drawbox}[3]{
    \def \angle {30}
    \def \xd {{2/3*cos(\angle)}}
    \def \yd {{2/3*sin(\angle)}}
    \def \x {{#1-1+(#2-1)*(\xd)}}
    \def \y {{#3-1+(#2-1)*(\yd)}}

    \draw (\x,\y) -- ({(\x)+1},\y) -- ({(\x)+1},{(\y)+1}) -- (\x,{(\y)+1}) -- cycle;
    \draw (\x,{(\y)+1}) -- ({(\x)+(\xd)},{(\y)+1+(\yd)}) -- ({(\x)+1+(\xd)},{(\y)+1+(\yd)}) -- ({(\x)+1},{(\y)+1}) -- cycle;
    \draw ({(\x)+1},{(\y)+1}) -- ({(\x)+1+(\xd)},{(\y)+1+(\yd)}) -- ({(\x)+1+(\xd)},{(\y)+(\yd)}) -- ({(\x)+1},\y) -- cycle;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawbox{1}{1}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code works fine when I don't use any `\def` and I substitute the definition of 'angle' in every occurrence of `\angle`, and substitute the definition of 'xd' in every occurrence of `\xd`, and substitute the definition of 'yd' in every occurrence of `\yd`, and substitute the definition of 'x' in ...
But of course that produces quite a long and very hard to read newcommand definition.

So what am I doing wrong that I don't seem to be able to do calculations based on my `\def`s?

Comment: Replace your defs with `\pgfmathsetmacro\xd{...}` etc. It's an expansion problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Question solved. If someone is interested in seeing the result, I used it as part of my answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224854/how-to-draw-stacked-cubes-of-different-sizes-and-colors/224868#224868

Answer (score 9):

The whole cube can be drawn in one `\draw` statement. The calculations can be also be done using the new TikZ library `math`, either via `\tikzmath{...}` or key `evaulate`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\newcommand{\drawbox}[3]{%
  \draw[
    evaluate={
      \angle = 30;
      \xd = 2/3*cos(\angle);
      \yd = 2/3*sin(\angle);
      \x = (#1)-1+((#2)-1)*\xd;
      \y = (#3)-1+((#2)-1)*\yd;
    },
  ]
    (\x, \y) -- ++(1, 0) -- ++(\xd, \yd) -- ++(0, 1)
      -- ++(-1, 0) -- ++(-\xd, -\yd) -- cycle
    (\x, \y+1) -- ++(1, 0) -- ++(\xd, \yd)
    (\x+1, \y) -- ++(0, 1)
  ;%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \drawbox{1}{1}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- I have also made the path specification less verbose by removing now unnecessary brackets of different kinds.
- Also I rearranged the path drawing. Line joins are done using rectangular or obtuse angles to avoid line joins with sharp angles, which stick outside the cube frame.

A variation using the new `pic` feature of TikZ 3.0 and XYZ coordinates:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\newdimen\unit
\newcommand*{\drawboxinit}{%
  \tikzset{%
    evaluate={
      \unit = 10mm;
      \angle = 30;
      \zx = 2/3*cos(\angle);
      \zy = 2/3*sin(\angle);
    },
    x=\unit,
    y=\unit,
    z={(\zx\unit, \zy\unit)},
    %
    drawbox/.pic={
      \draw
        (0, 0) -- ++(1, 0) -- ++(0, 0, 1) -- ++(0, 1)
        -- ++(-1, 0) -- ++(0, 0, -1) -- cycle
        (0, 1) -- ++(1, 0) -- ++(0, 0, 1)
        (1, 0) -- ++(0, 1)
      ;
    }  
  }  
}
\newcommand{\drawbox}[3]{%
  \path ({#1}, {#2}, {#3}) pic {drawbox};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \drawboxinit
  \drawbox{1}{1}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```