# draw a bundle of rectangular blocks

Tags: tikz-pgf

One cut to a cuboid results into two cuboids at most. Two cuts to a cuboid results into four cuboids at most. Three cuts to a cuboid results into eight cuts at most.

I want to draw illustrations for some problems associated with this sort of dissection of cuboids. I learnt from codes of Maarten Dhondt and AboAmmar
yet it still has lines along. Could you help?

[How to draw stacked cubes of different sizes and colors?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224854/how-to-draw-stacked-cubes-of-different-sizes-and-colors)

Best illustrations should be like this in the photo for the case of 3 cuts:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone} 
\newcommand{\drawbox}[4]{
     \pgfmathsetmacro \angle {30}
     \pgfmathsetmacro \xd {{2/3*cos(\angle)}}
     \pgfmathsetmacro \yd {{2/3*sin(\angle)}}
     \pgfmathsetmacro \x {{#1-1+(#2-1)*(\xd)}}
     \pgfmathsetmacro \y {{#3-1+(#2-1)*(\yd)}}
     \draw[fill=#4] (\x,\y) -- (\x+1,\y) -- (\x+1,\y+1) -- (\x,\y+1) -- cycle;
     \draw[fill=#4] (\x,\y+1) -- (\x+\xd,\y+1+\yd) -- (\x+1+\xd,\y+1+\yd) -- (\x+1,\y+1) -- cycle;
     \draw[fill=#4] (\x+1,\y+1) -- (\x+1+\xd,\y+1+\yd) -- (\x+1+\xd,\y+\yd) -- (\x+1,\y) -- cycle; } \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
 \usepackage{xcolor}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7] \drawbox{3}{1}{1}{blue!21}
 \drawbox{4}{1}{1}{blue!21} \drawbox{3}{0}{1}{blue!21}
 \drawbox{4}{0}{1}{blue!21}

 \drawbox{3}{1}{2}{blue!21} \drawbox{4}{1}{2}{blue!21}
 \drawbox{3}{0}{2}{blue!21} \drawbox{4}{0}{2}{blue!21}

 \drawbox{8}{1}{.431}{blue!21} \drawbox{9.4}{1}{.431}{blue!21}
 \drawbox{8}{-.420}{.431}{blue!21} \drawbox{9.4}{-.420}{.431}{blue!21}

 \drawbox{8}{1}{2.2}{blue!21} \drawbox{9.32}{1}{2.2}{blue!21}
 \drawbox{8}{-.40}{2.2}{blue!21} \drawbox{9.32}{-.40}{2.2}{blue!21}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One nice thing which I don't see mentioned on any of the answers to the other question is that `tikz` allows 3D coordinates `(x,y,z)`. In the solution below I've defined a `\cuboid` macro which draws a cuboid with its back (hidden) corner at the coordinate given in the argument. Most of the work goes into making it customizable:

- It takes keyword options `width`, `height` and `depth` (default 1) letting you set its size.
- It takes keyword options `front`, `top`, and `side` which pass their contents as styles to the corresponding sides of the cuboid.
- Other styles get applied to the whole cuboid (but are overridden by side-specific options).

Because it uses the built-in 3D coordinate system, you can also easily change the perspective by redefining the coordinates.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfkeys}
\makeatletter
\def\pgfutil@gobble#1{}
\pgfkeys{/handlers/.unknown to list/.code=%
  \let#1\pgfutil@gobble
  \pgfkeysalso{% or \pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.cd,
    .unknown/.code=% how to handle the difference between 'key' and 'key=value'?
      \ifx\pgfkeyscurrentvalue\pgfkeysnovalue
        \let\pgfkeys@temp\pgfkeyscurrentname
      \else
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pgfkeys@temp\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\pgfkeyscurrentname\expandafter=\expandafter{\pgfkeyscurrentvalue}}%
      \fi
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter#1\expandafter,\pgfkeys@temp},%
     .@clear list/.code=\let#1\pgfutil@gobble}%
}
\makeatother

\pgfkeys{
 /cuboid/.is family, /cuboid,
 depth/.estore in = \cuboidz,
 width/.estore in = \cuboidx,
 height/.estore in = \cuboidy,
 front/.estore in = \cuboidzStyle,
 side/.estore in = \cuboidxStyle,
 top/.estore in = \cuboidyStyle,
 .unknown to list = \cuboidOptions,
 default/.style = {width=1, height=1, depth=1, front=, side=, top=, draw},
}

\newcommand{\cuboid}[2][]{
  \pgfkeys{/cuboid, default, #1}%
  \begingroup
    \edef\x{%
      \endgroup
      \noexpand\begin{scope}[shift={#2}, join=bevel, \cuboidOptions]
        \noexpand\draw[fill,\cuboidyStyle] (0,\cuboidy,0) -- (\cuboidx,\cuboidy,0) -- (\cuboidx,\cuboidy,\cuboidz) -- (0,\cuboidy,\cuboidz) -- cycle;
        \noexpand\draw[fill,\cuboidxStyle] (\cuboidx,0,0) -- (\cuboidx,\cuboidy,0) -- (\cuboidx,\cuboidy,\cuboidz) -- (\cuboidx,0,\cuboidz) -- cycle;
        \noexpand\draw[fill,\cuboidzStyle] (0,0,\cuboidz) -- (\cuboidx,0,\cuboidz) -- (\cuboidx,\cuboidy,\cuboidz) -- (0,\cuboidy,\cuboidz) -- cycle;
      \noexpand\end{scope}
      \noexpand\pgfkeys{/cuboid/.@clear list}
    }%
    \x
}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{interior}=[fill=blue!50]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, fill=blue!20, z={(225:.8)}, x={(-10:1)}]
  \cuboid[interior]{(0,0,0)} \cuboid[front=interior, top=interior, width=2]{(1.5,0,0)}
  \cuboid[top=interior, side=interior]{(0,0,1.5)} \cuboid[top=interior, width=2]{(1.5,0,1.5)}

  \cuboid[front=interior, side=interior]{(0,1.5,0)} \cuboid[front=interior, width=2]{(1.5,1.5,0)}
  \cuboid[side=interior]{(0,1.5,1.5)} \cuboid[width=2, front={fill=white, draw=red, thick, dashed}]{(1.5,1.5,1.5)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Split cuboid]

I'm just learning this stuff myself; I guess my next step should be to try to figure out how to make this a node shape so that one can define anchors for adding labels, etc.